# Download file using fread in while loop - restrictions

Tags: php

I'm downloading a large file like that:

```
$fd = fopen($url, "r");

while(!feof($fd))
{
    set_time_limit(0);

    echo fread($fd, 4096);
    ob_flush(); 
    flush();
}
```

But in this script I have one problem - my web server has a three restrictions:

- max_execution_time - **max** 450 seconds,
- max_input_time - **max** 450 seconds,
- memory_limit - **max** 256M.

Finally I can download only a part of a file...

I'm downloading this file for watch a movie on my web site using flowplayer. 
How I can change this script - it should "refresh"/reload every downloaded (for example) 2MB. Is it possible?

Thanks.